# boost::range::detail::any_iterator doesn't play well with boost::zip_iterator

Tags: c++, boost, boost-iterators

Consider the following code:

```
#include <boost/iterator/zip_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/range/detail/any_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef boost::range_detail::any_iterator<
  boost::tuple<int &, char &>,
  boost::random_access_traversal_tag,
  boost::tuple<int &, char &> &,
  std::ptrdiff_t
> IntCharIterator;

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  std::vector<char> v2 = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};

  auto it = IntCharIterator(boost::make_zip_iterator(
    boost::make_tuple(v1.begin(), v2.begin()))
  );
  auto end_ = IntCharIterator(boost::make_zip_iterator(
    boost::make_tuple(v1.end(), v2.end()))
  );

  for (; it != end_; ++it)
    std::cerr << it->get<0>() << " " << it->get<1>() << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

It works as expected (i.e. prints "1 a\n2 b...") when compiled with no optimizations, but either segfaults or produces garbage when compiled with -O2 (with both clang-3.6.0 and gcc-4.9.2, boost 1.56.0) and I have no clue what's wrong.

Also, when IntCharIterator wrapper is removed, the code works as expected with either optimization level.

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in Boost.Range: [#10493 *Since 1.56, any_range with non-reference references can cause UB*](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10493) (warning: currently the bug tracker has an invalid SSL certificate). This was a regression introduced by the fix for [bug #5816 *any_range requires copyable elements*](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5816).

The workaround, oddly enough, is to make your `Reference` template type parameter `const`:

```
typedef boost::range_detail::any_iterator<
  boost::tuple<int &, char &>,
  boost::random_access_traversal_tag,
  boost::tuple<int &, char &> const,    // 'const', no '&'
  std::ptrdiff_t
> IntCharIterator;
```

If you want the code to work with pre-1.56 versions you can use a preprocessor conditional:

```
typedef boost::range_detail::any_iterator<
  boost::tuple<int &, char &>,
  boost::random_access_traversal_tag,
#if BOOST_VERSION < 105600
  boost::tuple<int &, char &>,          // no '&'
#else
  boost::tuple<int &, char &> const,    // 'const', no '&'
#endif
  std::ptrdiff_t
> IntCharIterator;
```

Note that in any case the `Reference` template type parameter should *not* have a `&`; per the [`zip_iterator` synopsis](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html), the `reference_type` is the same as the `value_type`, as it is a tuple of references:

> ```
> typedef reference value_type;
> ```